# Error adding SSL Support to a Jetty Server Clojure

Tags: ssl, clojure, jetty

I am trying to implement ssl in a jetty server; but the server never starts!!!

I create my server certificate files and this is the code:

```
(ns restserver.core
  (:require [ring.adapter.jetty :as jetty]
            [ring.util.response :refer [response])

(defn -main
  "A very simple web server using Ring & Jetty"
  [& args]
  (jetty/run-jetty (-> app wrap-json-response)
                   {:port (Integer. "8123")
                          :join? false
                          :ssl? true
                          :ssl-port 9999
                          :keystore "sitepkcs12.keystore"
                          :key-password "qwerty"}))

(defroutes app ....
```

Do I need to do something more??? I cannot figure out what is wrong!!!

I run

```
boot run
```

It tries to start but then nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that I have to change the join option to true and then the server can run!!!!